# How to remove image which is added to my app starting time with sleep

Tags: xcode

Hi i added one image to my app for getting at app launching with name as default after i removed that image frm my project and i added new one but i am getting old image some times but i cannt get where it is so any one can provide solution for my problem

Answer (score 1):

Bundle files are not removed when you install an app during development.  They are when you install from the App Store.  If you want a clean slate during development, then delete the app from your device before installing a new build.

Answer (score 0):

This is in your project Folder remove from them and Just add new image with same name to the Resources group in Xcode. It will end up in the root of the app bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the old image as default1  or something and add the new image as default. Now Clean the build settings and run the  app. I am sure it will work.